# Child Table variable allows NULL but the ON DELETE SET NULL still isn't working?

Tags: mysql

When I try to set the Foreign Key to ON DELETE SET NULL it won't create the table (ERROR 1005 (HY000):).  If I change it to ON DELETE CASCADE it works.  So I'm fairly certain that's the issue.

I have a table called ORDERHASSHIPPINGADDRESS that maintains the many-to-many relationship between CUSTORDER table and ADDRESS table.  When a customer deletes an order this can cascade through and delete the record in ORDERHASSHIPINGADDRESS, but when an address is deleted it shouldn't delete the record in ORDERHASSHIPINGADDRESS - then it should just be set to NULL until it can be updated to something else.  So I made sure the child table variable "addrID" allows NULL.  I made sure InnoDB allows this.  What else am I missing?  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
userName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
firstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
salt CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
HASH CHAR(40)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE ADDRESS (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
addName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
streetAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
state VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
zip CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
phone VARCHAR(10),
addrUserID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (addrUserID) REFERENCES USER(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE FUNDS (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
cardNumber VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
sudoName VARCHAR(25),
expDate DATE NOT NULL,
securityCode VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
billAddrID INT UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY (billAddrID) REFERENCES ADDRESS(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE CUSTORDER (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
invoiceDate DATE NOT NULL,
orderUserID INT UNSIGNED,
orderFundsID INT UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY (orderUserID) REFERENCES USER(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (orderFundsID) REFERENCES FUNDS(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE ORDERHASSHIPPINGADDRESS (
orderID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
addrID INT UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (orderID, addrID),
FOREIGN KEY (orderID) REFERENCES CUSTORDER(id) on DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (addrID) REFERENCES ADDRESS(id) on DELETE SET NULL on UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Am I just missing something obvious here?? If so - someone - please take pity on me.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL won't allow the SET NULL because I set the variable addrID as one of the PRIMARY KEYS so it cannot be null.